# Getting the error Undefined index: wp-login in my script?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This is the exact error:

```
Undefined index: wp-login in /home/the/path/file.php on line 159
Undefined index: wp-login in /home/the/path/file.php on line 161
Undefined index: wp-login in /home/the/path/file.php on line 162
```

Sometimes, I get `robots`, `title-tag` etc. instead of `wp-login`:

```
Undefined index: robots in /home/the/path/file.php on line 159
Undefined index: title-tag in /home/the/path/file.php on line 159
... and so on.
```

I am not using any WordPress plugin or anything else related to WordPress. Also, I am **not** accessing any array elements using `robots`, `title-tag` or `wp-login` as keys in the whole script.

Could anyone please tell me why do my error_log keeps filling with these errors?

This is the PHP code on line 159, 161 and 162:

```
$topics[substr($url_parts[3],0,-4)]
```

and this is the `$topics` array:

```
$topics  = ['technology'=>'Technology','android'=>'Android News','apple'=>'Apple News'];
```

Comment: Which file is "file.php"? Could you paste the lines it calls?

Comment: @Optiroot Do you mean lines 159, 161 and 162?

Comment: As @Optiroot asked; What is the code referenced at the lines referenced in the error?

Comment: It might be a bot that tried to access files with posted/query-string data in order to find exploits or etc.

Comment: @Zaky I have added more question details.

Comment: @OfirBaruch It looks like you are right. I accessed the page `http://my-webiste.com/wp-login.php` and the same error reappeared in the error log.

Is there any way I can stop them?